# Trying to create a check constraint on email with Regular Expression in SQL

Tags: sql, regex

I'm trying to add a constraint to check if the email match the following criteria:

An email address consists of alphanumeric characters, followed by an @ symbol, followed by alphanumeric characters, followed by a . symbol, followed by alphanumeric characters.

This is what I have and it's not working:

```
IF email  NOT REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9._%\-+!#$&/=?^|~]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$'
```

Can someone advise what I should do?

Comment: Google:  "regular expression email".  For me, the first hit is:  http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.

Comment: Try `'^[A-Za-z0-9._%+!#$&/=?^|~-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$'`

Comment: There are tons of email addresses that are valid that do match that description...

Comment: What's the database engine? Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc.